# ERROR:TypeError: can only join an iterable

Tags: python, web-scraping

I need to clean the data "{u'town': u'Bainbridge'} as only bainbridge

```py
def clean(self,text):
    if text:
        return ' '.join(''.join(text).split())

ustaApproved = self.clean(raw_ustaApproved)
certifications = self.clean(raw_certifications)
```

Comment: Your data appears to be the string representation of a dictionary, why not parse it to an actual dict (see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/988228/3001761) then access the town key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not quite clear from your post, but my guess it that `{u'town': u'Bainbridge'}` comes as a string. You need to parse it to a dictionary, but first, we'll turn it into JSON:

```py
import json

def clean(text):
    text = text.replace("u", "")
    text = text.replace("'", '"')
    return json.loads(s)

s = "{u'town': u'Bainbridge'}"
d = clean(s)
desired_value = d["town"]
# => Bainbridge
```

Comment: def clean(self,text):
                text = text.replace("u", "")
                text = text.replace("'", '"')
                return json.loads(s)
                if text:
                        return ''.join(''.join(text).split())
i get AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'replace'

Comment: How do you call the method?